# Why is using Middleware.statics not recognized?

Tags: javascript, express, intellij-idea

I am trying to access an html file that I created in vsCode through java using the app.use Middleware Function but it doesn't seem to be working.

[This is a view of the error and what I am trying to do exactly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aelv2.jpg)

```
try {
            app.use(Middleware.statics(Paths.get("src/www").toString()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`express.js` is a `node.js` framework, and `node.js` is a runtime environment that runs `javascript` codes on the server-side, these are completely different with `Java` programming language. see [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-java-and-javascript/)